# Numbering multiple paragraphs at once

Tags: macros, numbering, paragraphs

I am drawing up a document that has numbered paragraphs. 1-36 are numbered normally and I have no problems. However, on paragraph 37, I need something like:

> 35         Normal paragraph.
>
> 36         Normal paragraph.
>
> 37-46      The following paragraphs correspond to text text text text, text text.
>
> 47         Normal paragraph.

I'm numbering my paragraphs using:

```
\newcounter{xpar}
\setcounter{xpar}{1}
\newcommand{\xp}{\arabic{xpar}\stepcounter{xpar}.\hspace{.5in}}
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to number the paragraph with a 37-46, and then continue on with 47?

Comment: Your code contains some errors: instead of `\setcounter{xpar}`, you should use `\setcounter{xpar}{1}` (or another value) or `\stepcounter{xpar}`, and instead of `\newcommand{xp}{...}` you should use `\newcommand{\xp}{...}`.

Comment: Good catch; I already had those corrections...just typed this in here too quickly. Bad form on my part. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 8):

Add an optional argument for the "number of additional paragraphs" to the definition of your `\xp` macro. If the optional argument is empty, typeset the paragraph label as usual. If not, increase your custom counter as appropriate and also typeset the (new) label.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{xpar}
\newcommand{\xp}[1][]{%
  \stepcounter{xpar}%
  \arabic{xpar}%
  \ifx #1\empty
  \else
    \addtocounter{xpar}{#1}%
    --\arabic{xpar}%
  \fi
  .\hspace{.5in}\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\xp Some text.

\xp[3] Some text.

\xp Some text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think adding `#1-1` is a bit more intuitive.

Comment: I like this solution better, so I will delete mine.

Comment: Just a suggestion: you could add something like `\newlength\mylen` before the definition of `\xp`, and change the `\else` part to   `\else
    \addtocounter{xpar}{#1}\settowidth\mylen{--\arabic{xpar}}%
    --\arabic{xpar}\hspace{-\mylen}%` so that all the paragraphs would have the same indentation.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly.

Comment: @Robert: Thanks! Don't forget to accept my answer after some time if no better one comes along. :-)